# allowedkeys in Ember.js actions for Direction keys

Tags: ember.js

Basically what I am trying to do is turn an array into a list of divs that can be navigated by using the up and down arrow on the keyboard. I have the keyboard events working using any of the letters on the keyboard ('u', 'd', etc) but i can't work out how to do this with the arrow keys.

```
{{action 'testing' this on="keyPress" allowedKeys="d⇧f"}}
```

The above example will call my method testing when i press either 'd' or 'f' but does not trigger for the up arrow key.

Can anyone point me to a way to make this work with the arrow keys and esc as well? I will need to call different methods based on the different keys so i think i will need to add multiple action handler as well as the key does not get passed in as far as i know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get an answer on another forum and thought i would post a link to the answer as well as the answer here.

The post with the answer in it is http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/need-help-with-allowedkeys-on-action-for-special-keys/2960/4?u=seer

You can see the answer on jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/NQKvy/304/

You basically need to handle the keypress events by extending the view but the example also includes the whole list example where the keys change the selection and move oyu up and down the list.  A really great example.

This is how to handle the keypress but the jsfiddler is a more complete example

```
App.IndexView = Ember.View.extend({
didInsertElement: function() {
    // brings the view into focus in order to capture keyUps.
    // there are a few ways to handle this, this is just one.
    return this.$().attr({ tabindex: 1 }), this.$().focus();
},
keyDown: function(e) {
    var dir;

    if(e.keyCode === 38) dir = -1;
    else if(e.keyCode === 40) dir = 1;

    if(dir) {
        this.get('controller').send('changeSelection', { direction: dir });
    }
}
```

});